# Change file name of after downloading file from wget

Tags: linux, download, wget

I was trying to download file from link http://ligman.me/VSpodw using **wget**.
but it saving the file name as **VSpodw** as last characters of url . but when i download same file with browser it changes its name to the file specific. So how to do this file working with **wget**. How to save file with that original name rather than this random string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

use wget with the name of the file:

`wget http://ligman.me/eBook-Start-working-in-CRM.pdf`

or

`wget --content-disposition 'http://ligman.me/VSpodw'`

Comment: Thanx man **wget --content-dispotion 'url'** works exactly what i want . U saved my day

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-O` option:

```
wget http://some/url -O some.file
```

Caution: if your wget command downloads several files, they will be concatenated if the file you specify.

Comment: I dont know the name of file . It gets automatic when its redirect in browser. but with *wget** it postfix from url and save it as a name of file